# ObjectInputStream not reading in

Tags: java, serialization, objectinputstream

A class writes an elements of a "StudentRecord" array into it's own serialize file which I have checked if working properly; however, in another method(printstats) I deserialize the file using ObjectInputStream's readin and cast the object returned but the StudentRecord object is not being populated.

```
package adapter;
import java.io.*;
import model.*;
import util.FileIO;
public abstract class Gradebook implements Gradeable{
    private StudentRecord [] sturec;
    public Gradebook(String fname) {
        FileIO f = new FileIO("C:\\Users\\maya4\\eclipse-workspace\\Lab 5\\StudentInfo.txt");
        Student [] stuarr = f.readData();
        Statistics statobj = new Statistics(stuarr,f);
        //System.out.printf(" main determines that countr holds %d students\n", f.getCountr());

        statobj.calculate();
        if(DEBUG)
        {
            statobj.print();
        }

        for(int i =0 ; i<f.getCountr();i++)
        {
            sturec = new StudentRecord[40];
            sturec[i] = new StudentRecord(statobj, stuarr[i]);
            if(DEBUG)
            {
                sturec[i].printStudentRecord();
            }
        }

        for(int i=0;i<f.getCountr()-1;i++)
        {
            String tempstring= Integer.toString(stuarr[i].getId());
            String filename = tempstring +".dat";
            try {
                ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filename));
                out.writeObject(sturec[i]);

                if (DEBUG)
                {
                    System.out.printf("filename is %s ", filename);
                }
            }
            catch(FileNotFoundException fne) 
            {
                System.out.println("Error--" +fne.toString());
            }
            catch(IOException ioe) 
            {
                System.out.println("Error" +ioe.toString());
            }
        }
        System.out.println("\n");           
    }

    public void printstats(int stuid) 
    {
        //deserialize any file and print stats. 

        String Sstuid = Integer.toString(stuid)+".dat";
        try 
        {
            if(DEBUG)
            {
                System.out.printf("filename: %s", Sstuid);
            }
            //problem area!

            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(Sstuid));
            StudentRecord tempsr= (StudentRecord)in.readObject();


            System.out.printf("%d", tempsr.getSt().getId());
            //tempsr.printStudentRecord();
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException fne) 
        {
            System.out.println("Error--" + fne.toString());
        }
        catch(IOException ioe)
        {
            System.out.println("Error --" + ioe.toString());
        } 
        catch (ClassNotFoundException cnf)
        {
            System.out.println("Error--" + cnf.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to close the `ObjectOutputStream`, so the buffered data was never written to file. Using [**try-with-resources**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) is *highly* recommended.

Comment: I went back and closed both the ObjectOutputStream object and the ObjectInputStream object but I still get the error the input D:

Comment: What error in the input? Your question is very vague on what actually went wrong.

Comment: @Andreas What buffered data? Neither `ObjectOutputStream` nor `FileOutoutStream` is buffered.

Comment: Sorry, something goes wrong at  ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(Sstuid));

because tempsr isn't being populated

the program crashes at that line

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/ --- If program crashes, you should: 1) Print the full stacktrace, and 2) show the stacktrace in the question.

Comment: Still totally vague. 'Something goes wrong' and 'program crashes' are not recognized error messages. Try again.

Comment: the stacktrace is just the method in each class that is trying to execute when the program crashes, correct?

 1947.datjava.lang.NullPointerException
 at adapter.Gradebook.printstats(Gradebook.java:89)
 at driver.Driver.main(Driver.java:12)

Comment: Which is not where you said the problem was at all. You said it was at `new ObjectInputStream(...)`, and that 'the program crashes at that line'. Please make up your mind.

Comment: I'm confused, I said that the issue began with
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(Sstuid))
because when I set my studentrecord object to hold the object in.readObject returns in line 89 crashes because the studentrecord has null values and thus a nullpointerexception issue happens

Comment: I agree. You're confused. You are supposed to identify, clearly, the *actual line of code that threw the exception,* and what the exception was. You did neither. Instead you referred to *another* line of code, that *didn't* throw an exception, and you didn't identify the exception itself at all. You may as well have said that the problem is in `public static void main(String[] args)`, because after you execute it the program crashes. It would have been just as helpful.

Answer (score 0):

*If,* and you still haven't clarified this, the program crashes with an NPE at this line:

```
System.out.printf("%d", tempsr.getSt().getId());
```

either:

1. `tempsr` is null.
2. `tempsr.getSt()` returns null.

(1) would happen if you wrote a null with `writeObject()`, which you can check at the writing site.

(2) would happen if the underlying attribute was (a) null, (b) `transient`, or (c) `static`: or, e.g. if there is no underlying attribute, if the method somehow computed a null.